# Should I keep compiling against older versions of Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Since the release of Java 8, I found myself slowly becoming dependent on Java 8-specific features (ex. lambda statements) on a library project that I have *just* started.

I have seen many other projects which, to this day, still build against Java 7, or even Java 6, causing me to second-guess myself.

**Is it a good idea to immediately start building against the newest version of Java, or should I still use older versions?**

Note that unlike those other projects that have started back when Java 6/7 was the newest version, mine was started recently when Java 8 is the newest.

Comment: Who's the consumer for your library?  You?  Other projects?

Comment: Why be old when you can be fresh out of the farm?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: me and anyone else who wants to use it. It's an open-source project.

Comment: Depends on what you do. If and only if you want your application to be runnable without the latest version, you should use Java 6 or 7, otherwise the latest one.

Comment: If everybody would focus on legacy support, there would be no progress.

Comment: @Octopod: Then people who are stuck on Java 6 or 7 can't use it, if you use Java 8.  It's up to you whether you want to support those use cases.  That's really the only decision.

Comment: @Bubletan: I just want to provide a library for people to use. I guess my real concern would be: *how many less people am I allowing to use my library by restricting it to Java 8?*

Comment: I've been using java 8 for 2 years (even before offical release), and I've seen no problems. I released my open source project in java 8; it might be a problem since not a lot of programmers know java 8. but someone has to move on, right? I cann't go back to pre-8 days:)

Comment: The reality of this in product management for any product is that there are always people running on the original version, and every other version that has ever been released. As a rule of thumb you should support the version behind the current version, and if possible the one before that, and roll them forwards when a new version appears: but technical considerations may make that impossible, and if you can count your market you may find it isn't necessary.

Comment: The biggest practical effect of using java 8 is where it gets used. You might have a target audience that use some vendor tech and are stuck with 1.6 or 1.7 but this would be a small fragment of any user base. Frankly if 8 makes life easier for you, use it!  And the more useful things that depend on it, the faster the newer versions will be adopted.

Comment: Note that Oracle is no longer issuing public updates to Java 7: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons I can think of that would require staying with a pre-Java 8 JVM:

1. You are writing a library that is being used by a large group of people outside your organization who are still stuck on a pre-Java 8 JVM.  If you use the latest and greatest JVM, they won't be able to use your product anymore.
2. You are dependent on a 3rd party library that has not upgraded to Java 8 and breaks on Java 8.

Since you mentioned this is a new project, #1 is unlikely.  Even if you plan on having external users, if it's a new project, requiring the latest version of the JVM isn't really an issue.

Number 2 is also getting more and more unlikely as the more popular 3rd party libraries have released updates to work on Java 8.  Even the few stragglers are usually OK working on Java 8.  For example I use an ancient version of hibernate with Java 8.  I just don't use any Java 8 features in any mapped fields/entities.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 denotes a major change to the language since Java 5 (or perhaps its inception). If you are targeting specifically the changed language parts (which I guess you claim) then making it usable only by Java 8+ runtime makes sense.

When Java 5 occurred 10 years ago and you wanted to use all the new features introduced at the time (e.g. foreach statement, Enums etc.) into your own library development, what would you have done? I believe you would have made your library require Java 5 at the minimum. If you agree with that, then that (sound) logic applies consistently to your present situation as well.

Comment: Actually these days there was a [Retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) tool which could (with some limitations) backport your Java 5 app to Java 1.4.2 bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

For server side application, possibly a version or two prior to the current version as suggested by EJP.

On the client side however, I don't see any point in trying to support older Java versions.  The JRE has been auto-updating since at least Java 6.  It has gotten to the point where [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) launched applications cannot specify an earlier than current JRE.  Or rather, it can specify any JRE it chooses in the launch file, but that will be ignored in favor of the latest version installed on the user's computer.